# Developing with SQL Server Express and having problems with deployment to (full) SQL Server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I've been developing a simple ASP.NET MVC website locally using a SQL Server Express. Now I need to deploy the website to my hosting provider via FTP (no WebDeploy or anything like it).

When I upload the necessary directories and files (bin, Content, fonts, Scripts, Views, GLobal.asax, Web.config), I get following error:

> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The system cannot find the file specified]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
> error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
> server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
> name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
> connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 52 - Unable to
> locate a Local Database Runtime installation. Verify that SQL Server
> Express is properly installed and that the Local Database Runtime
> feature is enabled.)]

There is a full SQL Server 2014, not the Express Edition, on the server, which I know should direct me somewhere, but I'm complete lost on this and couldn't find any help either here on SO or somewhere else. Please note that there are a couple of related questions but none of them seems to address this issue.

I have already edited the connection string in the config file and accessed the database with the Management Studio. I can't check the connection between the website and the DB server (it's a plain webhosting, not a VPS) but I assume it should work since it is a huge hosting company and I've been getting this error consistently for last two days.

I have previously deployed the same project to Azure without any problems (mainly because that deployment was more or less one mouse click).

Comment: You probably have some reference to SQL Server Express in your config file....

Comment: You mention that you edited the connection string, but did you update the provider name?

Comment: @logixologist I've searched the whole project for any occurences of 'Express' and it doesn't seem to be the case. Is there any better way to check it?

Comment: @Nikki9696  [Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj653752(v=vs.110).aspx#sse) says it is the same (providerName="System.Data.SqlClient") for both cases (Express and Full). Am I missing something here?

Comment: Nope, if it's the same then that's not it  =)

Comment: Just for grins, search your project for "localdb" and see if it tried to create that anywhere, maybe for sessions or logins or something (this error message is one I'm used to seeing for LocalDB more than sql express)

Comment: @Nikki9696 Oh. Bot Web.config and .pubxml reference localdb. A good starting point! Thank you very much so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve all problems with my configuration based on comments by @logixologist and @Nikki9696, thank you both very much. I'll summarize all the necessary steps into this answer just in case someone else find them helpful, too.

**Edit connection strings entry**

```
<add
     name="ApplicationDbContext"
     connectionString="Server=__server__;Database=__db__;User ID=__user__;Password=__password__;"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

I have had even the name wrong - it must be the name of the DB Context(s) used in the project. In my case it is the name of the class derived from `DbContext`:

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : DbContext
{
 ...
```

Next, I searched the whole project for the term `localdb` and found it again in  Web.config in a block called `defaultConnectionFactory` a few lines above the `connectionStrings`:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    ...
```

I found a [blog on MSDN](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/davidobando/2012/08/14/changing-efs-default-connection-factory-from-localdb-to-sql-server/) which describes what one needs to edit. I only left out the `integratedSecurity` parameter, so my new `defaultConnectionFactory` block looks like this:

```
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type=“System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework“>
      <parameters>
        <parameter value=“Data Source=.; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True“ />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  ...
```

Beware: when copying the xml directly from the blog you need to use the correct parentheses instead of those there (or you'll get an inexplicable Error 500 just like I did).

And that was it, the deployed site connects to the SQL Server now without problems.

(This is what I really hate about ASP.NET stuff - all the time one saves by developing quickly and efficiently gets wasted on trying to figure how to deploy the damn thing because one just can't get a decent and *complete* piece of information on one place.)